# I'm trying to return the task that has not been completed

Tags: javascript

I want to use filter to check which task has not been completed but I'm doing something wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction

```
const task = {
  tasks: [
  {
    text: 'grocery shopping',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'clean yard',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: 'film course',
    completed: false,
  }],
  getTaskTodo(tasks)
  {
    console.log('its off');
    tasks.filter((item) =>
    {
      return item.tasks !== tasks
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: In the filter function you should be checking if the value of completed is true for every task in item. Therefore you could use. `tasks.filter(item => item.tasks.map(task => task.completed).every(true))`

Comment: Your syntax looks wrong.  You've got your function calls inside the task object.

Comment: @jmargolisvt, the syntax is fine; that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never return anything from your getTaskTodo.

Here is an example of how it could be fixed:

```js
const task = {
  tasks: [
    { text: 'grocery shopping', completed: true },
    { text: 'clean yard', completed: false},
    { text: 'film course', completed: false,}
  ],
  getTaskTodo()
  {
    return this.tasks.filter((item) => !item.completed);
  }
}

console.log(task.getTaskTodo());
```

**Explanation:**

- this : magic variable referencing the object
- !    : Logical not operator, turns true to false and false to true.

Comment: If you're using the "this" variable, you don't need to include it in the parameter list

Comment: @symlink Thanks, that was unused leftovers from the code in the question. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Return the entire filter function and you should be good:

```js
const task = {
  tasks: [{
    text: 'grocery shopping',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'clean yard',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: 'film course',
    completed: false,
  }],
  
  getTaskTodo(tasks){
    return tasks.filter(item => item.completed === false);
  }
}

let a = task.getTaskTodo(task.tasks);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: So, you are returning the tasks that have been completed, while the question was "has not been completed".

Answer (score -3):

Regarding your question:

```js
const tasks = [
  { text: 'grocery shopping', completed: true },
  { text: 'clean yarn', completed: false },
  { text: 'film course', completed: false }
]

const completedTasks = tasks.filter(task => !task.completed)
console.log(completedTasks)
```